# running predict for glm in batch mode

Tags: r

I try to run

```
    ltv_pos_model$prob3 <- predict(tree_before_deposit_3m_equal_100, newdata = ltv_pos_model,  
    type = "response")
```

in batch mode and this is what I get:

```
    Error in get(ctr, mode = "function", envir = parent.frame()) : 
    object 'contr.Treatment' of mode 'function' was not found
    Calls: predict ... model.matrix -> model.matrix.default -> contrasts -> get
    Execution halted
```

In interactive mode everything is OK

Thanks

Comment: sorry, this isn't reproducible. http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 .  To guess (since that's all that's possible without a reproducible example), it looks like you defined your own contrast function (`"contr.Treatment"`), and failed to define it in the batch file, *or* you meant to use `"contr.treatment"` and had a typo (more likely)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did't define a contrast function. It works well under interactive mode. Its something with the batch

Comment: if that solved your problems, you should either (1) delete your question (if you think it's too trivial to help future SO users) or (2) when you are allowed to [I think SO will force you to wait a few hours], write up your own solution as an answer.

Comment: That didn't solve my problem

Comment: OK, then, you still need to provide a reproducible example or we can't help you ...